# How To Hide YouTube Cards In Embedded Video?

Tags: html, youtube, embed

How can I hide [*cards*](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6140493?hl=en) when embedding a YouTube video?
I'm looking for something similar to hiding:

- Related: `?rel=0`.
- Title: `?showinfo=0`.
- Annotations: `?iv_load_policy=3`.